# How to add Margin On chart control of devexpress

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-wpf

is there a way to add a margin of both side of the chart of devexpress i need to add margin on left and right side of the grid before inserting any data on chart i tried to use this property `SideMarginsEnabled="True"` on my XAML but its not working any solution for this? Please See Image Below For reference

[image: Chart Margin in Left and right side]

Comment: check this http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q580823

Comment: I have tried that solution but it seems that its not working on my part

Comment: check for margin or padding property in chart properties..

Comment: I have tried that but sets all the chart form not inside the drawing i need to have a margin inside the data drawing in chart like it shows in my image above

Comment: you can also set this thing from code behind..

Comment: can you provide me a code? i have tried to set it from code behind like this ((XYDiagram2D)chart.Diagram).AxisX.Range.SideMarginsEnabled = true;